# How to send data from one form on a page with multiple forms through AJAX?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

**index.php**:

```
    <script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("form").submit(function(){
   var str = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url:"do.php",
     data: $("form").serialize(), 

  });
  return false;
 });
});
</script>

    <form action='do.php' method='post' id='toDo' name='toDo'>
        <input type='hidden' name='okok' value='one.txt'>
        <button type='submit' class='theButton'></button>
    </form>

    <form action='do.php' method='post' id='toDo' name='toDo'>
        <input type='hidden' name='okok' value='two.txt'>
        <button type='submit' class='theButton'></button>
    </form>
```

On the code above, there are 2 different forms  - each with the same name. Each form has an `input hidden` tag with its own unique value relating to a specific file in the directory.

If the user clicks the submit button in any of the forms, the value of the `input hidden` tag that was in the form that the user clicked the submit button in will be sent to the file **do.php**.

As the values of the `input hidden` tags are names of a text file, once it is sent to **do.php** (which can be seen below), the contents of the file will be retrieved (the contents are all numbers). The value that is retrieved from the text file (which is a number) will increase by 1. The new value that increased by 1 will rewrite the old value and be stored in the text file.

**do.php**:

```
<?php
    $filename = $_REQUEST[okok];
    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    preg_match("#\d+#", $content, $before_editing);
    $number_before = $before_editing[0];
    file_put_contents($filename, ++$number_before);

    $content = file_get_contents($filename);
    preg_match("#\d+#", $content, $after_editing);
    $number_after = $after_editing[0];   
?>
```

The code works perfectly without the AJAX script that I have included. With the AJAX script, only the value of the bottom form will be sent to **do.php** - so if I click submit on the first form, instead of sending the value **one.txt**, it'll send the value **two.txt**.

How would I fix the AJAX so that it works correctly?

Comment: this needs to be quoted `$_REQUEST[okok]` *for one thing* otherwise, [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) would throw an undefined okok constant warning. Plus, form does not bear the name attribute, only elements do.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for that, but how would I get the code to work?

Comment: you're welcome. Have a look at this Q&A http://stackoverflow.com/q/16638181/ it talks about using multiple forms. as does http://stackoverflow.com/q/4557628/ - Google "ajax multiple forms php"

Comment: ids need to be unique in a page. and using the same name for elements is allowed but not really a good idea. I bet you could fix this just by changing the names and ids to be unique

Comment: @Fred-ii- , thanks for the links but still can't get the thing to work. The form submits somehow but the data isn't sent through

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the problem:

```
data: $("form").serialize(),
```

This code finds and serializes all form elements in DOM, not just the one you wanted. Quick fix:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(){
        var str = $(this).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"do.php",
            data: $(this).serialize(), // serialize only clicked form, not both
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Note that there are various security issues in your code, including path traversal vulnerability.